# A script that deletes all the regular files (not the directories) with a .js extension that are in the current directory and its subfolders

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, scripting

Write a script that deletes all the regular files (not the directories) with a `.js` extension that are present in the current directory and all its subfolders.

The answer should only contain one command after the shebang line, I've tried the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -R *.js
```

… and:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f *.js
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name "*.js" -delete
```

Find all files in the current and child directories with the extension .js and delete the files.

Comment: The command above will not only delete files with the extension ```.js``` but also directories that include  ```.js``` extension at the end. A directory with name ```my_dir.js```.

You need to specify the type using ```-type f``` for file.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this remains the `find` command:

```
find . -type f -name '*.js' -exec rm -f {} \;
```

If however you want to stick to `rm` alone, it remains possible if you know exactly how many subdirectories lie under the place you're working in. For instance:

```
rm -f */*/*.js
```